# Tesseract - Reconhecimento OCR, invalid memory access

Tags: java

to tentando ler uma placa de um carro/caminhão usando o tesseract em java. Porém, está me apresentando erro. Não consegui entender ainda o motivo.

Segue:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    File imageFile = new File("C:/teste/placa_caminhao.jpg");
    Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract();
    tesseract.setDatapath("C:/teste/tesseract");
    tesseract.setLanguage("eng");


    try {
        String result = tesseract.doOCR(imageFile);
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (TesseractException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Erro:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory
>   access    at com.sun.jna.Native.invokePointer(Native Method)  at
>   com.sun.jna.Function.invokePointer(Function.java:470)     at
>   com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:404)    at
>   com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:315)    at
>   com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:212)  at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text(Unknown Source)  at
>   net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.getOCRText(Tesseract.java:437)   at
>   net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:292)    at
>   net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:213)    at
>   net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:197)    at
>   com.nexello.testesnexello.Main.jButton1ActionPerformed(Main.java:72)
>     at com.nexello.testesnexello.Main.access$000(Main.java:14)  at
>   com.nexello.testesnexello.Main$1.actionPerformed(Main.java:39)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro ocorria por estar faltando uma lib.
Apenas baixei o arquivo "wget https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/master/eng.traineddata", coloquei na pasta correta e deu certo.

Encontrei a solução no link abaixo:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800730/tesseract-running-error

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/219574)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica.